# Conexion a base de datos en carpeta sin ruta especifica

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net

Buen dia. Mi pregunta es si de alguna manera es posible conectar a una base de datos (Access) que no dependa de la ruta completa, el codigo que estuve usando es:

```
Dim conexion As New OleDbConnection("Provider = 
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\elder\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projets\Control de Versiones\Control de Versiones\DataBase.mdb")
```

pero solo la obtiene de esa ruta especifica, y yo necesito el programa "portable" que conecte a la base de datos desde la carpeta del programa pero ubicado en cualquier ruta del equipo.
Para realizar esto con archivos dentro del programa hacia uso de `(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath())` pero me es inutil para lo que necesito.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Porque es inutil? si es la forma de hacerlo.. tal vez no lo hiciste de la forma correcta?

Comment: Pues intente adaptarlo sin exito. Quizas puedes ayudarme por que no logre que funcionara...

Comment: pon las cosas que intentaste.. si directorypath devuelve la ruta de tu app, solo tenes qeu concatenarla

Comment: Encontré una solución, igualmente Muchas gracias por la respuesta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me funciono con

```
|DataDirectory|
```

Quedo de esta manera:

```
Dim conexion As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdb")
```